# make image link fit the container div and center the text inside it

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to create the image links in the main page of [this website](https://www.nobly.com/) .

The problem is that I can't get the text block to come to the center of the image. I don't think the a tag fits the container and I have no idea how to fix it. Help!

SCSS:

```
.home-img-links {
    @include flexCenter;
    margin: 4rem 0;

        .container {
            width: 600px;
            height: 350px;
            margin: 1rem;
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            filter: brightness(100%);


            .home-img-item {
                display: block;
                position: absolute;

                img {
                    @include easeOut;
                    max-width: 100%;
                    max-height: 100%;
                }

                .home-img-link-text {
                    @include easeOut;
                    color: $secondary-color;
                    max-width: 100%;
                    max-height: 100%;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 50%;
                    left: 50%;
                    text-align: center;
                    border: 0px solid $secondary-color;
                    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                    opacity: 0;
                    white-space: nowrap;
                    padding: 6rem 5rem;
                }
            }

            &:hover {
                box-shadow: 19px 52px 198px -31px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);

                .home-img-item img {
                    transform: scale(1.2);
                    filter: brightness(50%);
                }

                .home-img-link-text {
                    opacity: 1;
                    border: 10px solid $secondary-color;
                }
            }

    }
}
```

https://codepen.io/yubind/pen/MqJzgX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove your `position:absolute` from the home_img_item class (directly after the `container` class), and add `vertical-align:middle;`, then the text box centers both horizontally and vertically. You were very close! :)

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QVdRbN)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Works perfectly now. Thank you so much!